# Dropdown in angular not preselecting

Tags: angularjs, html-select

I am having trouble to pre-select dropdown item on my app. My dropdown is populating from different object and that work ok. There are all items that i want. In inspector I can see that angular is giving correct values to options. This is in html

```
<select name="mjerneJedinice" id="mjerneJedinice" ng-options="mj.naziv for mj in MjerneJedinice track by mj.id" ng-model="sredstvo.ukupna_kolicina_mj" class="form-control"></select>
```

I am binding object sredstvo to $scope.sredstvo and when I alert or debug code I can see that $scope.sredstvo.ukupna_kolicina_mj has value.

This is my controller:

```
eVinogradarstvo.controller('ModalSpremiSredstvoCtrl', function ($scope, ModalService, SredstvaService, CommonService, data) {

function getMjerneJedinice() {
    CommonService.getMjerneJedinice()
        .success(function (mjerneJedinice) {
            $scope.MjerneJedinice = mjerneJedinice;
            $scope.sredstvo = data.sredstvo;
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Greška kod dohvata mjernih jedinica ' + error.message;

        });
}
getMjerneJedinice();

$scope.sredstvaGrid = data.sredstvaGrid;
$scope.Ok = function () {
    SredstvaService.SpremiSredstvo($scope);
    ModalService.Cancel();
};

$scope.Cancel = function () {
    ModalService.Cancel();
};
});
```

what am I doing wrong?

I can post whatever you need.

PS everything else form model is binding correctly.

Best regards,

Veki

Comment: It would seem your `ng-model` (sredstvo.ukupna_kolicina_mj) is incorrect, or else the value is not set a you believe it is.

Comment: The object referenced by `sredstvo.ukupna_kolicina_mj` must be `===` to one of the `mj.naziv` in `MjerneJedinice` (and not just have the same attributes or the same id or whatever)

Comment: here, from console.log : kolicina_uporabe_mj:1
oh yes, when I choose some data in form(modal) and exit, and after that when I want to open modal again, data is there, it is binding then.

Comment: Add this code in `select` tag: `ng-init="tsredstvo.ukupna_kolicina_mj=MjerneJedinice[0]"`

Comment: Nope, its not working. I tried that, and sredstvo.ukupna_kolicina_mj=MjerneJedinice[0].id. But this means that he will always select first value. But I want him to select saved value. Its edit modal, so someone has already choose something

Comment: @JB Nizet does that mean that I  actually scant bind some value from 1 object to another with different values? Why is then ok when someone set initial value of some number?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: You said "sredstvo.ukupna_kolicina_mj must be === to one of the mj.naziv" and is that means that i cannot bind ukupna_kolicina_mj to mj.id? Because this objects are not the same..  but ukupna_kolicina_mj has value of mj.id...

Comment: Read the documentation. I'm completely lost in your example because the terms look like chinese to me. If you have a list of customers, and want the select box to populate a variable `selectedCustomerId` with the ID of a customer, and display the name of the customers, the code should be `customer.id as customer.name for customer in customers`. And to preselect a customer (the first one, for example), you need `$scope.selectedCustomerId = $scope.customers[0].id`.

Comment: I have already read it but found no solution... i dont need preselected for first value. I need to select data that is saved in db. It doesnt have to be first. Mayve 2nd 3rd or 6th. It depends on saved data

Comment: So, if the value to pre-select is a primitive value (string or number), just do `$scope.selectedCustomerId = theIdFromDb`. If it's an object, loop through the customers to find the one you want to preselect (for example, the one which has the same ID as the one you got from the DB), and do `$scope.selectedCustomer = theProductFoundByLoopingThroughTheCustomers`.

Comment: This didn't do the trick, but finally I have found the solution. Turns out that I need to convert value to string and use this:
<select name="mjerneJediniceKol" id="mjerneJediniceKol" ng-model="sredstvo.ukupna_kolicina_mj" convert-to-number class="form-control">
<option ng-repeat="mj in MjerneJedinice" value="{{mj.id}}">{{mj.naziv}}</option>
</select>

and not this one that I used
I think that he loads ng-model data before select data and he cannot recognize it.

Tnx everyone for your effort